# Can you embed and link files that reside on sharepoint?

Tags: office-365

I have a Visio diagram I'm trying to link into a powerpoint presentation.  Both files reside on the same Sharepoint site.  I tried adding the Sharepoint document library to my local computer as a mapped drive, using the method described [in this article](https://www.clouddirect.net/knowledge-base/KB0011543/mapping-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-network-drive), but I get an error saying the folder is not valid.  I'm not sure if this is due to a security restriction.

Anyways, the web app version of PowerPoint seems to be missing some features (there is no insert > object option that I can find).  I wanted to link the files so that if someone updates the Visio diagram, it will also update the associated presentation.  Is this possible within Sharepoint/Office 365, or does it only work with local files?

Comment: Try doing it totally offline with the desktop Visio and PowerPoint applications and put the final file on your OneDrive or Sharepoint site, and then open the file online from the web browser